# Laptop won't start properly after I spilled water on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, water-damage

Usual story: accidentally spilled water (just water, thankfully!) on my laptop - dried it out as best I could, left it overnight in front of a fan to drain and then the next day, took it apart to see if there was any residual moisture, or if anything had been fried.

From what I could see, nothing seemed damaged. I cleaned out any dust, made sure all the connections were still good, put it back together again - back to square one. It turns on (press the power button - power light comes on, but nothing else happens). Once I turn it on, I can't turn it off again - I have to pull out the battery/cut off the power source for it to turn off again.

I am yet to hook it up to externals (external keyboard/screen to see if that makes any difference - shall keep you updated).

Does anyone know what might be wrong with it? If so, what might I need to do to fix it?

**UPDATE:** plugged in an external Monitor and keyboard - no change. The power turns on, no hdd activity, the fans turn on but nothing else. Still need to pull out the battery to turn it off again.

Comment: when you turned it on, nothing came on the screen? can you connect another monitor to the laptop? was there hdd activity? maybe it did turn on but the screen is not working.

Comment: @Logman, like I said, I am yet to test it with externals, but so far from what I *can* tell, there is no hdd activity. (No noises going on). I will keep you updated when I do connect it (within the next hour)

Comment: look, if it powers on, it's probably fine. if it was gonna "fry" it would have happened already. There is bigger chance you messing something up taking it apart and putting it back together than it frying.

Comment: One night isn't enough. Let it dry for at least a week.

Comment: @DanielB Really..? Wow. Has anything I have done so far caused more harm than good?

Comment: It’s possible. Once I washed a notebook after a juice accident. Then, I put the parts in an airtight box together with silica gel for a week. Worked perfectly fine afterwards.

Comment: Let it dry **without batteries**, both the main and the coin cell for clock/CMOS, to avoid electrolytic corrosion. The coin cell may already need to be replaced, which might be causing the startup issue.